# sendkeys is not showing the proper result at the time of execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My selenium code is like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query")).sendKeys(emailId);
driver.findElement(By.id("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

I have also used `Keys.ENTER` in last line.

But it is not showing the actual result at the time of execution. So what is the problem?

Comment: Just a quick code review comment... if you are going to use the same element on multiple lines, store the result of the `.findElement()` in a variable. You are actually scraping the page 4 times in the above code when it only needs to be scraped once.

Comment: Like this:     `WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query"));
    input.click();
    input.clear();
    input.sendKeys(emailId);`

Comment: Your last line is incorrect... you are using `By.id()` when it should be `By.cssSelector()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution and the answer is:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtKeyword.input-medium.search-query")).sendKeys(emailId  + Keys.ENTER);
```